# Node Sequelize migrations/models is it possible to share the same code?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new at Sequelize so be patient.

I started up a new project using Sequelize
and migrations so I've got like this:

### migrations/20150210104840-create-my-user.js:

```
"use strict";
module.exports = {
  up: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    migration.createTable("MyUsers", {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      first_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      last_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      bio: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
      }
    }).done(done);
  },
  down: function(migration, DataTypes, done) {
    migration.dropTable("MyUsers").done(done);
  }
};
```

### models/myuser.js:

```
"use strict";
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var MyUser = sequelize.define("MyUser", {
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    bio: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return MyUser;
};
```

as you can see the table definition
is both on the migration and the model file.

I'm wondering if there is a way to share
the code ?

I mean I don't like to have logic in two files
if a field change I've to update twice.

### UPDATE

following the Yan Foto example below
a different way may be cleaner.

### schemas/users

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    name: 'users',
    definition : function(DataTypes)  {
        return {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            firstname: {
                type:DataTypes.STRING
            },
            lastname: {
                type:DataTypes.STRING
            },
            email: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                unique: true
            },
            username: {
                type:DataTypes.STRING,
                unique: true
            }
        };
    }
};
```

### models/users

```js
'use strict';

var Schema = require('../schemas/users');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define(
        Schema.name,
        Schema.definition(DataTypes),
        {
            freezeTableName: true ,
                instanceMethods: {
                countTasks: function() {
                        // how to implement this method ?
                }
                }
        }
    );
};
```

### migrations/20150720184716-users.js

```
'use strict';

    var Schema = require('../schemas/users');

    module.exports = {

        up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
                return queryInterface.createTable(
                Schema.name,
                Schema.definition(Sequelize)
                );
        },

        down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
            return queryInterface.dropTable(Schema.name);
        }

    };
```

Comment: I know this is pretty old but generally the point of the migrations is that you don't change them after they run, so if you need to add fields to your model, you create a new migration file to make that change to your database, so you wont always have 1 migration for 1 model. You can have many migrations that tweak a table and the model definition should be the combination of changes. If you don't need this functionality you can just use sequelize.sync() and your models will dictate your table in the database without migrations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wondered the same thing as I started using sequelize and here is my solution. I define my models as bellow:

```js
module.exports = {
  def: function(DataTypes) {
    return {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      username: DataTypes.STRING,
      password: DataTypes.STRING,
      createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
      updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    }
  },
  config: {}
};
```

Where `def` defines the attributes and `config` is the optional `options`  object accepted by [`define`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#definemodelname-attributes-options-model) or [migration methods](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/). And I import them using the following code:

```js
fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/PATH/TO/models')
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename);
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var name = file.substring(0, file.lastIndexOf(".")),
        definition = require(path.join(__dirname + '/models', file));

    sequelize['import'](name, function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
      return sequelize.define(
        name,
        definition.def(DataTypes),
        definition.config
      );
    });
  });
```

For the migrations I have a similar approach:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable(
      'users',
      require(path.join(__dirname + '/PATH/TO/models', 'user.js')).def(Sequelize)
    );
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
  }
};
```

Comment: I ended up with quite the same way.I updated the thread.Thanks for the clue and feedback

Comment: @Whisher If there's anything that I should add to make it eligible as correct answer, please let me know.

Comment: Interesting approach. How do you handle mutations such as adding a column?