# Sequelize js orm migration with seeder

Tags: sequelize.js

Is there a way to populate the db
(migration + seeds)
using sequelizejs ORM ?

my migration

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var Schema = require('../src/schemas/users');

module.exports = {

    up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        return queryInterface.createTable(
            Schema.name,
            Schema.definition(Sequelize)
        );
    },

    down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        return queryInterface.dropTable(Schema.name);
    }

};
```

take a look at [Node Sequelize migrations/models is it possible to share the same code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512039/node-sequelize-migrations-models-is-it-possible-to-share-the-same-code)

### First attempt

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var Async = require('async');
var Models = require('../src/models');
var  User = Models.users;

/**
 * Users to insert.
 */
var users = [
    {

        firstname: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        lastname: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        email : 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        username:'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        password:'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    }
];

var calls = [];

function createUserPromise(current, index, users) {
    calls.push(function(callback) {
        User
            .create(current)
                .then(function(user) {
                    callback(null, user);
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    return callback(err);
                });
            });
}
users.forEach(createUserPromise);

Async.parallel(calls , function(err, results){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        var info = results.map(function(result){
            return result.dataValues;
        });
        console.log(info);
    }
    process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Follow the template scaffolded by `seed:create` from [sequelize-cli](https://github.com/sequelize/cli):

`$ node_modules/.bin/sequelize seed:create --name my-seed-name`

Then run your seed:

`$ node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:seed`